# QSqlRelationalTableModel or QSqlQueryModel

Tags: sql, qt

Description:

I use `QTableView` with database in first form for listing records. 
I create second form for editing single record. This record has field, referencing to other table (FK). I tried to use `QSqlRelationalTableModel` with `setFilter` (for selecting single record) and `setRelation` (for processing FK and combobox). I planned to use `submit` for saving record. I didn't have success with this scheme because `setFilter` and `setRelation` are conflicting. I think I should use `QSqlQueryModel` for selecting single record.

Questions:
How should I save record (`QSqlQueryModel` is read-only)?
Is this method right and the best for my target?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but my solution was something like this:
Probably you will need to change somethings but it works.

```
self.model = QSqlRelationalTableModel()
self.model.setTable("FK The table Name")
self.model.setRelation(index, QSqlRelation("Pkey table", "The id field", "The value field you want"))
self.model.select()
```

After you set the relation creat a mapper if you want to

```
self.mapper = QDataWidgetMapper()
self.mapper.setModel(self.model)
relModel = self.model.relationModel(index) #the same from the SetRelation
self.YourCombBox.setModel(relModel)
self.TourCombBox.setModelColumn(relModel.fieldIndex( "The value field you want"))
self.mapper.addMapping(self.YourCombBox, int)
self.mapper.toFirst()
```

and to save you just go and

```
_insertRecord = QSqlRecord()
_insertRecord.append(QSqlField(int, QVarinat.WhatEverTypeItIs))
quer = QSqlQueryModel()
quer.setQuery("SELECT id FROM TheTable where Name = '%s'" %(YourComboxCurrentText()))
_insertRecord.setValue(int, quer.record(0).value("id"))
self.model.insertRowIntoTable(_insertRecord)      
self.model.select()
```